# How to structure higher level effect (between clusters) in mixed-effect models

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I am working on a multilevel analysis aiming to investigate factors that impact student GPA. The data comes from 16 different schools. To include school effects, we are using a mixed effect model (with random intercepts). However, I would like to understand the effect of school tuition on student GPA and I am confused if this should be included as a fixed effect or random effect, since it is information about the higher level cluster (school).

My `lme4` models I have constructed so far are either:

```
gpa ~ student_study_hours + student_income + 
       student_physical_activity + (1|school / school_tuition)
```

OR

```
gpa ~ student_study_hours + student_income + 
       student_physical_activity * school_tuition (1|school)
```

Comment: School tuition should be a fixed effect.

Comment: Thank you. I was worried that may be a redundacy or colinearity effect since every student from the same school will have the same tuition

Answer (score 2):

The second option (`... + (1|school)`) is probably correct.  In general the variables that you use as a grouping variable should be *categorical* and *exchangeable* (i.e., you should be able to switch labels without changing the meaning). You could conceivably treat tuition as categorical ("low", "medium", "high"), but even then it probably wouldn't be sensibly thought of as exchangeable.

In general modern mixed-model frameworks don't 'care' at what level the fixed effects vary. It does determine whether you can model their variation across units — for example, you could conceivably model the variation of the effect of student family income across schools, but you can't model the variation of the effect of tuition across schools because it doesn't vary within schools.